# create and check unique name against existing

Tags: node.js

I wrote this  to check a newly generated name against what already exists in the DB...

..it's working, but it feels poorly written. Any suggestions? just trying to learn, thanks.

```
function createNewName (){
    const shortName = uniqueNamesGenerator({
      dictionaries: [adjectives, colors, animals], 
      length: 3
    }); 
    return shortName;
  };
  
  async function checkNameExists(name){
    //check name against DB
    const nameExists = await User.findOne({'name':name},function(err,result){        
    });    
    if (nameExists){      
      return true;
    } else {      
      return false;
    };    
  };
  
   async function checkNewName(name, exists=true){     
    while (exists==true) {
      exists = await checkNameExists(name);
      if (exists){
        name = await createNewName();        
      };
    }    
  };

  let name = await createNewName();
  await checkNewName(name,true);
```

Comment: what is the point of `while` loop in the `checkNewName` function, I think it's unnecessary?

you can replace `if(nameExists){return true} else {return false}` with `return !!nameExists`

Comment: @rudolf-manusachi while loop was to make sure name was not already assigned, and if so, try another...  But, yes, feel like there is a better way to do that??